# Display distortion on newer kernels/drivers

Tags: nvidia, kernel, display, gpu-driver, ubuntu-mate

My laptop is stuck running Lubuntu 12.04. Every attempt to update to a newer version of any distro results in my screen becoming unusable. I have tried Debian based and RPM based distros. The boot goes well up to the splash screen, then when the desktop loads, I get the desktop image as shown below. This happens for all desktop environments I have tried (XFCE, LXDE and MATE). Currently, I am trying to update to Ubuntu Mate 15.10.

[image]
This is what I normally get after either a `dist-upgrade` or even when fresh installing anything newer (currently attempting Ubuntu Mate 15.10)

[image]
Had this happen once. I was attempting to switch to TTY2 at the time and also pressed the power button to try to get it to shutdown (Ubuntu Mate 15.10).

Currently working install details and machine info:

- Lubuntu 12.04.5;
- Kernel version 3.2.0-92;
- Machine = Toshiba Tecra A4 (Model PTA40A-1D2004);
- Memory = 1GB;
- Achetecture = 32bit x86 Pentium M;
- Display driver = nVidea NV43M GeForce Go 6600 and NOUVEAU driver.

Any ideas on what the cause could be and how to fix it?? One thing I have attempted is to hold back the driver updates prior to performing a `dist-upgrade` (`sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`) to seemingly no gain.

Comment: Why are you using the nouveau driver ? Have you tried the additional drivers app for an Nvidia driver ?

Comment: I tried to activate the proprietary driver from the terminal, then switch to the desktop, but couldn't get it to work. I managed to do it by completely disabling the video drivers and running from the VGA generic display instead. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While watching the TTY1 screen during boot from the LiveCD, I noticed an error come up “GPU Lockup - switching to software fbcon”. I found on another forum that when the boot options screen comes up (with the try, install, etc options on it), press F6 and select `nomodeset` from the list of options. This allowed me to see the install screen and successfully install Ubuntu Mate (rather than get a fuzzy screen).

Once the install completed I was stuck with a low resolution desktop until I loaded the proprietary driver (nVidea v304.128) in the Additional Drivers options. Now I have an up-to-date Ubuntu Mate install with a crisp screen.